# Outlook Table Issue

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have some problem with outlook. I ran a free litmus test. In every outlook version, it's looking good except Outlook 2007 and 2010. First, it wasn't looking good in every outlook version... then here I read some post and made a few changes... And now It's ok except outlook 2007 and 2010..  **The left column loadings but the right column don't start until the end of the left column**....

Please help me out.. I can't put My html code here or add any image here.. It says I need 10 reputation.. But I'm new here

Comment: How can I add HTML code here?

Comment: Just copy and paste the code into the question. You can do that with 1 rep.

Comment: I can't.... 
I can put 30000 word  once at a time... my code word number is 47k plus...

Comment: Lol, in that case you will get no help here. No ones going to bother with that. You should take relevant code out and give us that. If you cannot do that I guess your on your own because we have no idea what your talking about.

Comment: here is the code...
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="122" align="center" valign="top"><table align="left" width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="30"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <table align="right" width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: the problem is... left column is loading but right column doesn't start until the end of the left column. In every outlook version it looks good except 2007 and 2010...Please help me out.